# How do I include the generated assemblies of Maven modules in a multi module build?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, flexmojos

I have a multimodule project, and I'm starting with just one child module:

```
<modules>
    <module>x</module>
</modules>
```

When module x builds it too uses the assembly plugin to put together some of its artifacts into a tar.gz. However, it's main artifact type is not a tar.gz, it's a SWC (I'm using [FlexMojos](http://flexmojos.sonatype.org/)). The idea is to create an assembly from other child assemblies, basically unzipping multiple tars and zipping them into a single one.

I want to pull out this tar.gz in my parent assembly, but using the moduleSet/binary combination below I only seem to be able to get the other SWC artifacts.

```
<moduleSets>
  <moduleSet>

    <includes>
      <include>blah:x</include>
    </includes>

    <binaries>
      <outputDirectory>${module.artifactId}</outputDirectory>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
    </binaries>

  </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
```

I know about the issues with using the assembly plugins with multimodule builds - I don't have them because my childs have a different parent to this POM.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: This seems possible. Try clarifying your question. It's not clear exactly what's not working and what you need.  Perhaps show the files (name,type,path) your build is producing and what you want to produce (name,type,path), instead.